# Getting a data class from a given value of that class in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have two definitions that

```
data Person = Person Name Surname [Projects]
data Employees = Employees [Person] Salary
```

And I want to get the corresponding person from a given name by using the person list in employee and make some changes in the corresponding person. For example, I want to add a project to the list of project of the person that I want to do the project. How can I do this in Haskell?

The function signature should be like

```
myfunction :: Employees -> Name -> Employees
```

Comment: This is not legal Haskell code, I suppose you mean `data Person = Person Name ...` – type names and constructors must be capitalised. Also, your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with classes (note that Haskell classes – _type classes_ – are something quite different from OO classes as you have in e.g. Java).

Comment: You're right. Sorry for bad explanation. Just because I'm quite new in Haskell and I'm used to c-like languages

Comment: No problem, but please edit your question accordingly. Also, it could use some more explanation on what exactly you want (example input and corresponding result).

Comment: It seems like `Employee` should be renamed something like `Group`. An employee is a particular kind of person, not a group of them.

Comment: The question title still doesn't make sense. The function signature is helpful, but are you sure you don't mean `Employees -> Name -> Person`? Again: it would be helpful if you gave some _example input_ and the expected result. And: it's also considered good etiquette, at least, to show some _own effort_ to solve the problem!

Comment: My purpose is to print the new Employees list after the changes in Person. So my function signature is that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write this most directly by just pattern matching and using `map`.

In this case we might start by writing a small helper function to perform the local modification a single `Person` value and use something like `map` to apply our transformation to a whole bunch of other data. So we might have

```
 updatePerson :: Name -> Person -> Person 
 updatePerson targetName (Person name sur projects)
   | targetName == name = Person name sur (NewProject : project)
   | otherwise = Person name sur projects
```

and then we can write a little more code to uniformly  apply this transformation to our `Employee` data

```
myFunction :: Person -> Person
myFunction name (Employee ps salary) = 
  Employee (map (updatePerson name) ps) salaray
```

In your scenario this is the right thing to do. However, presumably we're going to be accessing parts of these data structures a lot so it makes sense to optimize for it a bit! By writing a few helper functions to manipulate our data types we might see how to get a more general approach:

```
personName :: Person -> Name
personName (Person name sur projects) = name

modifyProjects :: ([Project] -> [Project]) -> Person -> Person
modifyProjects f (Person name sur p) = Person name sur (f p)
```

and then writing something like

```
 myFunction name (Employee people salary) = Employee (map go people) salary
   where go p | personName p == name = modifyProject ... p
              | otherwise = p
```

Now I wrote this with helper functions rather than pattern matching directly because it suggests we use Haskell's built in feature for generating these functions, records.

```
data Person = Person { _name :: Name
                     , _surname :: Surname
                     , _projects :: [Projects]
data Employees = Employees {_people :: [Person], _salary :: Salary}
```

And then we can do something like

```
myFunction name e = e {_people = map go (_people e}}
  where go p | _name p == name = p {_projects = New :: _projects p}
             | otherwise = p
```

but now this is still clunky, Haskell's record system is a little tough to work with. This is actually the impetus for a whole lot of crazy powerful libraries implementing "lenses" which give us the ability to implement these record like transformations using a kit of generic combinators. I provide the corresponding lens code for an example of Haskell scaling up to do something cool, but either of the 3 alternatives I mentioned above are perfectly fine and much less complex

```
import Control.Lens
data Person = Person { _name :: Name
                     , _surname :: Surname
                     , _projects :: [Projects] }
data Employees = Employees {_people :: [Person], _salary :: Salary}

makeLenses ''Person
makeLenses ''Employees

myFunction n e =
  e & people.traverse.filtered pred.projects %~ (:) "New Project"
  where pred person = person^.name.to (== n)
```

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation without any complaining in spite of my bad explanation...